# How do I convert this recursion to dp

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/triangle) problem. I believe my solution does work, but it takes more time. This is my solution - at each step, I calculate the minimum sum if I choose i or i+1 index.

```
class Solution 
{
    public int minimumTotal(List<List<Integer>> triangle) 
    {
        return minSum( triangle, 0, 0 );
    }
        
    public int minSum( List<List<Integer>> triangle, int row, int index )
    {
           if( row >= triangle.size() )
               return 0;

            int valueAtThisRow = triangle.get(row).get(index);

            return Math.min( valueAtThisRow + minSum(triangle, row+1, index), 
                             valueAtThisRow + minSum(triangle, row+1, index+1));
    }
}
```

I think more appropriate way is to use DP. Please share any suggestions on how I can convert this to a DP.

Comment: I was looking for memoization. But I am also open to understand teh bottom up version as well.

Comment: Are you open to Python or C++ solution? Or just Java version?

Comment: C++ or Java are fine Daniel.

Comment: Please review the C++ code, and comment?

Comment: @PavanDittakavi, not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I would memoize your code, in [this way](https://pastebin.com/0wLrdL62).  Hope it helps!

Comment: @PavanDittakavi - please review the answers and if you find one of them is helpful, please accept it.  People spend time helping others, and would like feedback too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that bottom-up solution is simpler here and does not require additional memory, we can store intermediate results in the same list/array cells

Walk through levels of triangle starting from the level before last, choosing the best result from two possible for every element, then move to upper level and so on. After that `triangle[0][0]` will contain minimum sum

```
for (row = n - 2; row >= 0; row--)
    for (i = 0; i <= row; i++)
          triangle[row][i] += min(triangle[row+1][i], triangle[row+1][i+1])
```

(tried python version, accepted)

Answer (score 0):

DP bottom up approach:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minimumTotal(vector<vector<int> > &triangle) 
    {
        vector<int> mini = triangle[triangle.size()-1];
        for ( int i = triangle.size() - 2; i>= 0 ; --i )
            for ( int j = 0; j < triangle[i].size() ; ++ j )
                mini[j] = triangle[i][j] + min(mini[j],mini[j+1]);
        return mini[0];
    }
};
```

Python version:

```
def minimumTotal(self, triangle: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        
        if not triangle: return 
        size = len(triangle)
        res  = triangle[-1]    # last row
        
        for r in range(size-2, -1, -1):      # bottom up
            for c in range(len(triangle[r])):
                res[c] = min(res[c], res[c+1]) + triangle[r][c]
        
        return res[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Top down solution: we compute shortest paths (`agenda`) to each cells row by row starting from the triangle's top.

**C# code**

```
public int MinimumTotal(IList<IList<int>> triangle) {
    int[] agenda = new int[] {triangle[0][0]};
    
    for (int r = 1; r < triangle.Count; ++r) {
        int[] next = triangle[r].ToArray();
        
        for (int c = 0; c < next.Length; ++c) 
            if (c == 0)
                next[c] += agenda[c];
            else if (c == next.Length - 1)
                next[c] += agenda[c - 1];
            else
                next[c] += Math.Min(agenda[c - 1], agenda[c]);
                    
        agenda = next;
    }
    
    return agenda.Min(); 
}
```